# setting source to imageview with uri in android generates error

Tags: android, uri, android-imageview, android-assets

I am confused why it is happening because my little knowledge says it should not happen. I have couple of images stored in android asset directory in apk in fact in some directory structure like:

```
    Assets --> aphotos --> launch50 ---> launch501.jpg
```

Now for example I want to set an image to an imageview widget pro grammatically like following: -

```
    Uri uri =    Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/"+context.getString(R.string.photoroot)+"/"+fldr+"/"+introphoto);
    System.out.println("Image URI: "+uri.toString());       
    imageView.setImageURI(uri);
```

where "fldr" and "introphoto" come from the database. While doing this it generates the following error in "LogCat": -

```
11-22 19:23:46.689: W/ImageView(12990): Unable to open content: file:///android_asset/aphotos/launch50/launch501.jpg 11-22 19:23:46.689: W/ImageView(12990): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android_asset/aphotos/launch50/launch501.jpg (No such file or directory) 11-22 19:23:46.689: W/ImageView(12990):   at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
```

Can anybody tell that why it's happening because image is there?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820816/how-to-get-uri-from-an-asset-file) it is obviously not working well to get a URI for an asset file.

I think you need to do it with a stream:

```
    String path = context.getString(R.string.photoroot)+"/"+fldr+"/"+introphoto;
    InputStream is = getAssets().open(path);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    is.close();
```

Comment: The question was why it can't be done without opening the stream which I don't want actually. Image is there, setImageURI method is there then why is not working?

Comment: This worked for me:- [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8197435/1326579) Thanks for kind replies.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use this code:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);

Glide.with(this).load("file:///android_asset/img/fruit/cherries.jpg").into(imageView);
```